# Необходим совет для выполнения задачи

Tags: android

Нашел вот такое задание на должность Junior Android:

```
Сделать 2 экрана:
1-й экран принимает номер телефона с форматированием его по маске ввода номера. 
После валидации номера, переход на 2-ой экран.
2-ой экран - вводится смс код 4-х значный.
На обоих экранах присутствует навигационный бар.
На экране смс кода стоит 60 секундный таймер, по завершению которого вместо текста отсчёта появляется кликабельная текстовая кнопка (например, далее).
Дизайн можете взять с любого топового приложения по вашему вкусу.
Роутинг можно сделать либо на фрагменты либо на view.
Желательно без xml (научим).
```

Собственно вопросы:

1. Номер телефона с форматированием его по маске ввода номера. Первая идея просто в какой нибудь EditText закидыват номер и проверять на его длину. Но что делать с кодами разных стран (которые имеют разную длину?)
2. На обоих экранах присутствует навигационный бар. Что под ним имеется ввиду? Navigation Bottom Bar?
3. Роутинг можно сделать либо на фрагменты либо на view. что понимается под этим словом? На чем верстать (2 Activity, или 1 Activity + 2 Fragment?)
4. Желательно без xml (научим). Это как я понял не использовать макет в Layout, а писать его из кода?

Comment: Сделай валидацию шаблона по своему городу хотя бы, ну боттом бар нет смысла делать, т.к. на одном валидация с переходом на другую про пин (тулбар с бэком и усе), одна активити и два фрагмента, без xml, kotlin anko бы помог как надо)

Comment: Но я хз на счет таких тестовых заданий. Прям слишком для джуна. Обычно дают rss распарсить или ещё что, чтобы продемонстрировать свои навыки работы с сетью (рест).

Comment: Не горячитесь, мне первый раз на джуна надо было сделать приложение погоды. И было оно немного сложнее. Так что не переживайте, делайте так как знаете и считаете нужным, ибо если вы начнёте искать верное решение, применяя чужие со своими у вас получится каша малаша ибо вы не будете понимать что да почему вы так делаете. А при нормальном собеседовании вопросы будут что да почему вы делали так как они бед отличаться от того как это делает ревьюер(скорее всего тим лид с 10ти летним стажем).

Comment: Во вторых вы не знаете, что именно они хотя увидеть ваши умения писать код (типо знешь то, это и ещё корзинку вот этого) или  всё-таки правильно решать задачи: правильно подобрать архитектуру, паттерны и используемые библиотеки (хотя зачастую это второе). У меня тогда ревьюер очень впечатлился умению использовать ConstraunLayout, хотя я только по сути начал использовать (советую почитать и использовать). Так что возьмите листик, набросайте самое верное решение и делайте!!!